# Cheerio Error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to iterate over table rows.But when I use $ to find an element from inside the .each function,it raises the above error.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
.....
var headers = $('[id*=tableone] tbody tr')

 headers.each(function(header_index, header_elem){
    console.log($(header_elem))                         => exception here
   })
```

Comment: do you requiring in code:cheerio = require('cheerio'),and response.body var $ = cheerio.load(item.body)

Comment: yes Morteza. I am already retrieved headers first .

Comment: do you getting response correct?response consisting functions,checking response from site.

Comment: Voting to close. Needs a [mcve]. This code doesn't reproduce the given error--it should work fine.